# upload pictures to google drive without alerting the user

Tags: python

Is there a way to upload pictures with python without disturbing the user.
I need to upload the data on google drive.the problem is that the web browser opens every time.i don't need to alert the user everytime I upload

Comment: How do you upload? Show us the related code!

Comment: If you use APIs then no browser will open.